# Serve both static website & SPA (node.js) with NGINX

Tags: nginx

I need a way to serve both static html website and SPA using NGINX.

- https://website.com -> should be the static index.html page.
- https://website.com/register -> should point to SPA powered by node.js webserver.

So, if there's an appropriate static html route it should be served with NGINX, any other route should be served by node.js webserver.

e.g.

https://website.com/about -> served by NGINX because there's about.html
https://website.com/register -> served by node.js because there's no appropriate static page for this route (there's no register.html).

I've created the following configuration, but it doesn't seems to work properly.

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;

    root /var/www/website.com;

    location = / {
        try_files /index.html =404;
    }

    location = /index {
        return 404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html =404 @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @backend;
}
```

Breaking it down for you. The `try_files` directive

> Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing;

So

`$uri` - look for the exact file as defined in the path. Useful for static files like css, images, js, etc..

`$uri.html` look for the exact file with a `.html` extension.  This would get your `about.html`

`$uri/` - looks for it to be a directory then uses the `index` directive to look for `index` or `index.html`

`@backend` - send to the proxied application would be responsible for returning 404

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration could probably be simplified to this:

```
root /var/www/example.com;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}

location @backend {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer solve the problem? It only sounds like you are simplifying his config file.