# How can I serve both my website AND a node.js app with NGINX?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a website at `https://mydomain.co.uk`
This has a form which uses nodemailer, a server.js file, an app.js file to handle the formdata.
I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04), to leverage nginx as a reverse proxy. I have included the following in my `mydomain.co.uk` server block

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

And now when I try to visit `https://mydomain.co.uk` I have a too many redirects error.

I have run certbot on `mydomain.co.uk` and before I attempted to set up the reverse proxy, it was running absolutely fine.

I know the proxy config is the reason for the error in my browser, However I don't know how to set up the config.

I have already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422629/serve-both-static-website-spa-node-js-with-nginx)but cant see how it applies to what I'm doing.

**Extras**

I have the `server.js` file running with `pm2` and I have set the env to production with

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

the `ecosystem.config.js` looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "myserver",
        script: "server.js",
        watch: true,
        env: {
            "PORT": 3000,
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        env_production: {
            "PORT": 80,
            "NODE_ENV": "production",
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Since following the answer below my config file now looks like this

```
 location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

        }
```

and my server.js file now looks like this

```
var path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500; // CHANGE TO WHATEVER
// middleware
var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, "/html");
// app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static(htmlPath));
app.use(express.json());
```

However now, express seems to be only serving one single html file, and not the whole html directory..

The reverse-proxy is working, as it is serving from express, but what do I need to do to ensure express serves the whole html directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi dude :) You need proxy pass to the node's port. You uncorrecyly configure port and directives in nginx right now. However, nginx sending request to 80 , so , it is default , and again.. and it repeat as loop infinite.

Correctly directives

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mydomain.co.uk;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    # There 3000 port your development nodejs running port

    location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I have the whole website within the 'public' folder of my node app? And have the entire website at port 3000?

Comment: If your core directory public folder for nodejs it is ok. But other cases you need add context inside in server directive

Comment: context is :     root /var/projects/nodeapp/public;

Comment: or other case location / directive itself solve your route requests for nodejs app

Comment: please ignore the edit i accidentally made to your answer

Comment: i changed it to the previous